# How to set up multi-threading in Spring Batch?

Tags: java, multithreading, spring, spring-batch

I've successfully set up a tutorial Spring Batch project.  I'd really like to know if it's possible to make it multi-threaded at the "Spring level".

The basic idea of what I want is to make a list of tasks or task steps and let them be picked up and worked on by independent threads, ideally out of a pool limited to 'n' number of threads.

Is this possible?  If so, how?  Could someone show guide me to that point from where I'm currently at?

The simple project I have is from this tutorial [here](http://java.dzone.com/news/spring-batch-hello-world-1).  It basically has different tasks which print out a message to the screen.

Here's my current simpleJob.xml file, which contains the job details:

```
<import resource="applicationContext.xml"/>

    <bean id="hello" class="helloworld.PrintTasklet">
        <property name="message" value="Hello"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="space" class="helloworld.PrintTasklet">
        <property name="message" value=" "/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="world" class="helloworld.PrintTasklet">
        <property name="message" value="World!\n"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="taskletStep" class="org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep" >
        <property name="jobRepository" ref="jobRepository"/>
        <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="simpleJob" class="org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleJob">
        <property name="name" value="simpleJob" />
        <property name="steps">
            <list>
                <bean parent="taskletStep">
                    <property name="tasklet" ref="hello"/>
                </bean>
                <bean parent="taskletStep">
                    <property name="tasklet" ref="space"/>
                </bean>
                <bean parent="taskletStep">
                    <property name="tasklet" ref="world"/>
                </bean>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="jobRepository" ref="jobRepository"/>
    </bean>
```

My appContext contains the job repository bean (`SimpleJobRepository`), transaction manager (`ResourceLessTransactionManager`) and job launcher (`SimpleJobLauncher`).  I can provide this code if desired as well, I just didn't want to bog down this post with tons of XML.

Thanks very very much for any help!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Create a Split and you will be able to use multithreading between the different branches.
Use a TaskExecutor to define your parallelism policy.

See [Multi-threaded Step](http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/reference/html/scalability.html#multithreadedStep)

Be sure to use the latest version of Spring Batch if you want to use multithreading and the MapJobRepository (prior to latest version, this JobRepository was not thread safe).

Comment: for scaling and implementing parallel executions you can refer this - https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/task/SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor.html#setConcurrencyLimit-int-

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at Jean answers'. An easy way is create a bean of SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor and associate a tasklet to use this bean, like that.

```
<bean id="simpleTaskExecutor"
    class="org.springframework.core.task.SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor">
    <property name="concurrencyLimit" value="10"/>
</bean>

<batch:job id="jobTest">
    <batch:step id="step1">
    <!-- throttle-limit default is 4. Increase this to ensure that a thread pool is fully utilized -->
        <batch:tasklet task-executor="simpleTaskExecutor" throttle-limit="20">
            <batch:chunk />
        </batch:tasklet>
    </batch:step>
</batch:job>
```